# Flatten directory structure to a new destination, delete obsolete files from destination

Tags: linux

Directory 'd1' which has multiple sub directories with files than end with .bin

I wish to copy all of those .bin files to 'd2' disregarding the directory structure (ie, flatten) to make it easier for a web app to find those files. 'd2' directory should be kept up to date and not contain old files.

The only way I can think of doing this I really don't like:

```
cd /d1
mkdir /d2.new
find . -type f -name "*.bin" -exec cp -f {} /d2.new
rm -rf /d2
mv /d2.new /d2
```

The problem I see with the above are:

I really hate using 'rm -rf' in a script, thinking if it could go wrong, it will, and have disastrous consequences.

Between the 'rm' and the 'mv' completing, the 'd2' directory doesn't exist, which could cause problems for services that require that directory.

But without the last 2 lines, 'd2' will contain old files, which I don't want either.

There doesn't seem to be a way to force 'mv' to rename a directory to another that already exists.

Both directories are on the same server, so finding something that only copies when the files don't match would be a bonus.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41897612/2320453

Comment: Why aren't you using `mv`? That's the obvious solution. But your explanation doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I don't see how 'mv' is the obvious solution when I'm trying to copy files ? However, the comment by duenni looks like exactly like what I'm looking for.